# Updating a component's state once all images have loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, state

I'm trying to update a component's state once all the images have loaded. The idea is to be able to show all the images in a grid simultaneously to the user, instead of them seeing each image load one at a time.

**Here's my component** that loads the images.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from "react";

//Storage to show the images on the grid
var imagesSources = [];

/* 
 * ==============================================================
 * Component to show a grid random images
 * ==============================================================
 */
 function RandomImageGrid(props) {

  var childrenLoaded = 0;

  const [loading, isLoading] = useState(true);
  console.log("loading state: " + loading);
  console.log("Loading images...");

  //When all the <img> have loaded, then update the state so we know loading is done
  const handleChildLoad = () =>  {

    childrenLoaded++;
    console.log("child: " + childrenLoaded);

    if(childrenLoaded === props.gridSize){
      isLoading(false);
      console.log("loading state: " + loading);
      console.log("All images have loaded");
    }
  };

  //an array of image paths for the src attribute in the <img> tags  
  imagesSources = ['cats_01.jpg', 'cats_02.jpg', 'cats_03.jpg', 'cats_04.jpg', 'cats_05.jpg', 'cats_06.jpg', 'cats_07.jpg', 'cats_08.jpg', 'cats_09.jpg']

   return (
    
    <div key={props.imageType} className="catcha-images">
      { imagesSources.map((source, gridPosition) => {
        return(
          <div>
            <img
              src={source} 
              onLoad={ () => {handleChildLoad()}}
            />
          </div>
        )
      }) }
    </div>
    )
  }

export default RandomImageGrid;
```

I think I am not understanding something about the React lifecycle because **the current code gives me the output** like:

```
loading: true
RandomImageGrid.js:42 Loading images...
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 1
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 2
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 3
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 4
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 5
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 6
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 7
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 8
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 9
RandomImageGrid.js:50 loading: true
RandomImageGrid.js:51 All images have loaded
RandomImageGrid.js:41 loading: false
RandomImageGrid.js:42 Loading images...
```

But **what I expect**, would be more like:

```
loading: true
RandomImageGrid.js:42 Loading images...
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 1
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 2
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 3
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 4
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 5
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 6
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 7
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 8
RandomImageGrid.js:46 child: 9
RandomImageGrid.js:50 loading: false
RandomImageGrid.js:51 All images have loaded
```

So the state doesn't update how I would expect, and there seems to be a second render that takes place. But I'm not sure why or how this is happening.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are performing a side effect from your component code directly (writing to console). You need to use `useEffect` for that, so wrap the `console.log("loading state: " + loading);` and the one below in a `useEffect` call with `loading` as dependency and see if you will get the satisfactory output.  P.S. When the loading state changes, you will still get "Loading images" message because you always display it, no matter if  `loading` is true or false. So try that and see how it goes.

Comment: Thank you, this did seem give me expected results. So just to understand, using console.log outside of a useEffect() hook is causing the state to update since it's a side effect?

Comment: No, using console.log outside of `useEffect` causes it to be executed every time **while** the component is rerendered. It doesn't have any effect on the state. Any code inside `useEffect` is guaranteed to be run **after** the component is rendered. And with dependencies, you control if that's after every render or only when the specified part of the state is changed.

Comment: I see, this was more a matter of understanding the asynchronous nature of how updates happen. I was reading this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-state-in-react-explained-with-examples/ and it clarified your comments. Thanks for the explanations here. Very helpful.